# Unable to connect to FACEIT CS:GO servers.No AV,no firewall,good network connection

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

I'm new to faceit and almost each time I want to play I'm forced to join a server(mostly german ones,while I live in middle-east) which is unreachable for me.I can ping the server of course but I get `retrying public(...)` messages in console and finally fail to join the match,an as the result I get AFK bans each time(now 18 hours,for something that I've no control over it,it's just painful)

I've whitelisted FACEIT and CS:GO in Win10 firewall config,I've no active AV,my internet connection is fairly good,and I asked my ISP and they said they don't block any port.

I tried scanning the CS:GO ports of one of those servers via `Nmap` and all of them are filtered...

I've reported this multiple times to FACEIT and got no response.

Answer (score 1):

Open steam, rightlick on CS:GO, click properties. Under general you'll find launch options. Add

`+clientport 2700X` to them, where X can be 6, 7, 8 or 9. If one number doesnt work, try a different one. That solved the issue for me.

Further reading: [LAN Settings playing with friends](https://support.faceit.com/hc/en-us/articles/207953889-LAN-Settings-Playing-with-friends)

Comment: Tnx for reply.The exact port differs each time(last time was 27025) and btw I had tried the option `clientport` before and no luck.I think FACEIT itself can alter the launch options.
But I'll try using the exact port number that FACEIT client telling me next time,after my ban came to an end ofc,and come back here again

Comment: For me `+clientport 27008` works while ...007 didn't.